# How To Change LDAP Variables?

Tags: python, django, ldap

I need to change `django-auth-ldap` variables such as `AUTH_LDAP_URI` with dynamic inputs from user. How do I manipulate these variables in the memory?

I tried changing imported variables expecting library automatically detects it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to store in the database. Before authentication method called I fetch and modify these variables in `LDAPBackend` class and in `authenticate` method. If you know better solution I'm very eager to hear that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).